# remove one seq elements from another seq in scala

Tags: scala

Is there any efficient way of removing elements present in Seq `one` from Seq `two`

```
val one = Seq("A", "B")
val two = Seq("A", "B", "C", "E", "F")
val out = two.map {
  for (n <-one){
    _.filterNot(_ == n)
  }
}
```

expected output `Seq("C", "E", "F")` , `empty or null of one` should also be handled
But I'm getting error `Cannot resolve overloaded method 'map'`

can anyone suggest what am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the simplest way to do this efficiently:

```
two.filterNot(one.toSet.contains)
```

This uses `contains` to see whether an item is in `one` or not. `one` is converted to a `Set` as this implements `contains` more efficiently that `Seq` which does a linear search.